# Superfish 3rd level menu partially "on top" and partially "on bottom " in IE

Tags: jquery, superfish, css

I have a superfish menu that works great in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but not IE (I know, I konw... common problem). My problem is that my third level menus appear "partially" on top of the 2nd level menus, but not entirely.

The border and background color appear on top of the 2nd level menu, but the text itself from the 2nd level "bleeds through" and shows mixed with the 3rd level menu.

Here are a couple screen shots:

IE:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

I can make the background colors quite different (red/blue for example) and show they're "on top" of each other correctly - here they're just slightly darker shades of gray.

I have no idea where to look in my CSS file, which is here: http://www.willoughby-ind.com/desktopmodules/az.dnnmenu/templates/willoughby/superfish.css

And my actual site, which is here: http://www.willoughby-ind.com

Any assistance would be appreciated. It took me days to get this far, and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this line in your `iehacks.css`:

```
.sf-menu li {
    z-index:999;
}
```

Changing that to a value lower than your third-level menu z-index should work

Comment: That didn't work for me. I wound up with the following in my iehacks.css file. It doesn't look as I want it to (and as it looks in other browsers, but at least the text is no longer jumbled up)

    ul.sf-menu li ul li ul li  
    {
        z-index: 30;
        position: fixed;}
    
    ul.sf-menu ul ul
    { z-index: 40;
    position: fixed;
    }

Answer (score 0):

My solution didn't produce the results I WANT, but at least the text is no longer jumbled up. Now IE pops the 3rd level menu up within the secondary menu - instead of off to the side it's right below. Not perfect, but I think it's usable.

I put the following into my iehacks.css file:

```
ul.sf-menu li ul li ul li
{
    z-index: 30;
     position: fixed;}

ul.sf-menu ul ul
{ z-index: 40;
  position: fixed;
}
```

[image]